# Why does the sequential write to a journal file speed up if it is in a different file system?

Tags: mongodb

As per MongoDB documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling,

> To speed the frequent sequential writes that occur to the current
>   journal file, you can ensure that the journal directory is on a
>   different filesystem

storing the journal file on a different file system speeds things up.  Is it because two different hard disk spindles are at work?  Just wanted to understand the mechanics of this optimization tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

If you are using physical rotating hard drives, there is significant performance benefit from separating the journal activities onto a separate (preferably dedicated) physical drive.

The benefits are not the same if you're using SAN hardware.  And to an extent are lessened by larger drive caches available in modern hard drives.  And it's a different story again with SSD.

The main factor with spinning disks is seek time - the time that it takes for the read/write head to get to the right part of the disk.  Hard disks are arranged with circular tracks. To get to a specific block on the disk, the head moves to the right track, and the disk spins around to the right place (the disks keep spinning of course, so it's simply a matter of waiting for the right place to come around).

This doesn't take much time, but when it's happening a lot it adds up.

When you have the primary activity and the journal activity on the same drive, the head has to rapidly move between the two (many, really) locations that the system needs to look at.

If you have your journalling on another physical drive, then the head on that drive can be almost (or perhaps more accurately, relatively) static, with the ability to more rapidly access the correct track / location required.  Meanwhile the other drive (with the primary activity on it) will be more efficient also, because the head will not be constantly seeking back to the where the journal entries are being written between the other activities required to keep the database running.

This benefit applies to most database systems and many other applications where there is a constant sequential writing to disk going on at the same time as other mixed disk activity.

You don't get the same profile if you're using SAN, because even if it appears to be separate file systems, it's actually likely to be striped across many drives which are both cached and shared.

SSD has a different profile also, because there is no physical seek time.